# Conditions imposed on graph automorphism leave the "voltage" on graph nodes identical?

Tags: graph-theory, stochastic-processes, automorphism-group

We call $\pi$ a graph automorphism on a graph $(V,E)$ if $\pi:V\to V$ is a bijection such that $xy\in E\iff \pi(x)\pi(y)$ is an edge, and $\phi(xy)=\phi(\pi(x)\pi(y))$, where $\phi$ is the conductance.

I want to show that, given two distinct points $a,b$ we have that $f(x)=f(z)$, if it holds that $\pi(a)=a$, $\pi(b)=b$, $\pi(x)=z$. 
Here, $f$ is some arbitrary harmonic function (in the sense of stochastic processes) at every node $x\in V\backslash\{a,b\}$, that is $$f(x)=\sum_{xy\in E}\frac{\phi(xy)}{\phi(x)}f(y)$$
Here, the conductance on a vertex/node $\phi(x)$ is the sum of all the conductances on the adjacent edges.

I am not sure how to visualise a graph automorphism that satisfies the stated conditions, other than trivial ones. So I continued without trying to use that intuition, but got stuck all the same.

I tried writing
$$f(x)=\sum_{xy\in E}\frac{\phi(xy)}{\phi(x)}f(y)=\sum_{xy\in E}\frac{\phi(\pi(x)\pi(y))}{\phi(x)}f(y)=\sum_{xy\in E}\frac{\phi(z\pi(y))}{\phi(x)}f(y)$$
but I don't see how the given conditions can be used to further modify this expression into the desired form (which would be $\sum_{zk\in E}\frac{\phi(zk)}{\phi(z)}f(k)$).

In particular, I think I'm missing how to include the relevant conditions imposed on $\pi(a)$ and $\pi(b)$. Could anyone give some suggestions as to how to proceed?

Comment: $z$ is the image of $x$ under the automorphism. I edited that, forgot to change it when I changed the notation.

Comment: It seems that your function $\phi$ is defined on vertices as well as on edges, so don't you want to also have the condition $\phi(\pi(x))=\phi(x)$ for all $x\in V$ in your definition of automorphisms?

Comment: The conductance of the vertex is a function of the adjacent edges, and is completely determined by the adjacent edges. So I think that would be unnecessary, as it already follows from the condition on the edges.

Comment: Are you sure you want $f$ harmonic on all of $V$ and not just, say $V\setminus \{a,b\}$? For $f$ harmonic in the sense that you describe above, $f$ must be constant (assuming the graph is finite at least).

Comment: No, you are right, which is why I said $f$ is harmonic at every point $x\neq a,b$. I will edit my original post to make this more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll asume that $(V,E,\phi)$ is a connected, finite, weighted graph and that $f$ is harmonic on $V\setminus \{a,b\}$ (if the graph is not connected, then any such $f$ will be constant on all of its components save for the common component of $a$ and $b$). Let $(X^{x_0}_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ denote the associated simple random walk started at $x_0$. 
That is, 
$$
\mathbb{P}(X^{x_0}_{n+1}=y|X^{x_0}_n=w)=\begin{cases} \frac{\phi(wy)}{\phi(w)} & w\not\in \{a,b\}, wy\in E \\
1 & w=y\in \{a,b\} \\
0 & else\end{cases}
$$
and $X_1^{x_0}=x_0$.

Then, by assumption, $(\pi(X_n^{x}))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ has the distribution of $(X_n^{z})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$, and hence $(f(\pi(X_n^{x})))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $f(X^x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ are both bounded martingales (since $f$ is harmonic). Let $\tau$ denote the first hitting time of $\{a,b\}$. Then, applying the optional sampling theorem, we get

\begin{align}
f(x)=\mathbb{E}f(X_1^x)=\mathbb{E} f(X_{\tau}^x)&= f(a)\mathbb{P}(X^x_{\tau}=a)+f(b)\mathbb{P}(X^x_{\tau}=b)\\
&= f(a)\mathbb{P}(\pi(X^x_{\tau})=a)+f(b)\mathbb{P}(\pi(X^x_{\tau})=b) \\
&= f(a)\mathbb{P}(X^{z}_{\tau}=a)+f(b)\mathbb{P}(X^z_{\tau}=b) \\
&= \mathbb{E} f(X^z_{\tau}) \\
&= f(z)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look up the the concept of martingales, and then accept your solution once I fully understand the proof. You introduced some concepts that are new to me.

Comment: Oh... I just thought you would know about martingale theory since you said that this was the stochastic process sense of harmonicity.

Comment: I guess you could give a more hands-on proof that $\mathbb{E}(f(X_{\tau}))=\mathbb{E}(f(X_1))$ (we're in a very finite world).

Comment: I think you made a typo when you defined the random walk, as you used $w\not\in\{a,b\},\space wy\in E$ twice. Other than that, the result seems quite clear and concise. If I may ask, how did you think of fusing all these different concepts to obtain the desired result? Or is that just standard when you know more about martingales?

Comment: Oh sure... there was definitely a typo. Basically, the random walk moves according to the weights until it hits $a$ or $b$, at which point it just stays still forever. As to how I thought of this, this is the somewhat classical way of thinking about discrete harmonic analysis from a stochastic point of view. Discrete harmonic functions relate to martingales of the simple random walk the same way harmonic functions relate to martingales of Brownian Motion. So the simple random walk generating martingales is completely integral to the way I think about discrete harmonic functions to begin with.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your clear explanation, I appreciate it.

Comment: Hey, I was just reviewing this problem and I came to realise I don't fully understand which of the three cases from the Optional Samping Theorem you are using here. We must either have that the stopping time is less than some integer, or that it is almost surely finite, or that it has finite expected value, with some additional constraints. Does the boundedness of the martingale imply that the stopping time is finite?

Comment: I agree that the usual phrasing of Optional Sampling might not tell you exactly what is up. That the stopping time is finite just comes from the fact that the graph is finite - for each $z$, there is some probability $p_z>0$ that the random walk started at $z$ just immediately executes a path to $a$ or $b$. Then, letting $p:=\min_{z} p_z$, we know that at all times, if the random walk has not yet stopped, there is a probability $p$ that it will immediately head to the boundary and stop.

Comment: Hence, if $\ell$ is the maximal length of one of these paths, then the probability that $z$ has not terminated in $n+\ell$ steps is at most $(1-p)^n$. Letting $n$ to $\infty$ gives you that $\tau$ is almost surely finite.

Comment: As far as the exact application of the OST goes, it's more natural to say that $f(X_n)$ being a martingale implies that $f(X_{\tau\wedge n})$ is a martingale where $\tau\wedge n=\min \{n,\tau\}$. However, since $\tau$ is almost surely finite, $f(X_{\tau\wedge n})\to f(X_{\tau})$ almost surely. But $f$ is bounded, so almost sure convergence implies $L^1$ convergence.

Comment: Edit: The bound I actually argued is that the probability that $z$ has not terminated in $(n+1)\ell$ steps is at most $(1-p)^n$, sorry. Basically, you start the Random Walk at $z$, and you need to check whether the walk stays on the path you fixed between $z$ and $\{a,b\}$. Then, the first time it deviates from said path, we get another chance to connect, but this might first happen after $\ell$ steps.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, makes it much clearer. I missed the "finite" assumption initially, also, because I had not made it in my original assumptions. I'll try to see if I can say anything about infinite graphs, using everything you've shared here. Very kind of you to explain so thoroughly.

Comment: Your statement is not true for infinite graphs. Consider the graph $\mathbb{Z}^2$ with edges between nearest neighbours, $a=(0,0)$, $b=(1,0)$ and uniform conductances (i.e. $\phi(e)=1$ for every edge $e$). Let now $\pi(x,y)=(x,-y),$ which fixes $a$ and $b$ and maps $\xi=(0,1)$ to $\psi=(0,-1)$ and define $f(x,y)=x+y$. This function is easily seen to be harmonic. However, $f(\xi)=1\neq -1=f(\psi)$.